# How can I expect that a certain method is called with a specific block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I want to be able to test with rspec that a specific gem called with a specific block:

The code looks like this

```
SomeGem.configure do |config|
  config.username = "hello"
  config.password = "world"
end
```

and the spec that I have written looks like this:

```
it 'sets valid gem configuration' do
  credentials = lambda do |config|
    config.username = "hello"
    config.password = "world"
  end

  expect(SomeGem).to receive(:configure).with(credentials)
end
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: expect(SomeGem).to receive(:configure).with(credentials)
Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.
```

Any ideas on how I should be testing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather try to assert the externally visible effects. Suppose you have a `SomeGem.configuration` method that you can use to retrieve the configured values, then you could write

```
describe 'configuration block' do
  subject do
    lambda do
      SomeGem.configure do |config|
        config.username = "hello"
        config.password = "world"
      end
    end
  end

  it { is_expected.to change(SomeGem.configuration, :username).to("hello") }
  it { is_expected.to change(SomeGem.configuration, :password).to("world") }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I used the code `expect(SomeGem.username).to eq 'hello'` instead.

Comment: This syntax won't work, because `is_expected` is simply `expect(subject)`, not `expect { subject }`, you have to write it explicitly.